# Snowflake timestamp conversion in java 8

Tags: java, java-time, snowflake-schema

I am getting date from snowflake in below format

```
2021-07-13 00:00:00.000 -0600
```

What string format should i use to convert it to java 8 LocalDateTime?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of a parsing format? Or taken a look at other examples?

Comment: Why `LocalDateTime` when there is an offset of `-0600`? Use an `OffsetDateTime` and parse it with a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS x")`. You can extract a `LocalDateTime` from the `OffsetDateTime` afterwards, there's a method `.toLocalDateTime()`.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is much overused and not the right class for you to use here, as @deHaar already spotted. In which time zone do you want the result? If there is an answer to that question, convert to a `ZonedDateTime`. It gives you everything that a `LocalDateTime` can give you and more. If you are happy with the UTC offset from the string (-0600 in the example), just parse into an `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS ZZZZ`

Comment: Details, you probably wanted a dot rather than a comma between `ss` and `SSS`. Otherwise I believe it’s correct.